# My SVN tags/1.0.0 is empty, how do you fix it

Tags: svn

What do you do when the changes you made to a repository have not been commited and you taged the remote.

Both the trunk and the tags/1.0.0 are empty on the remote.

Locally it seems that the SVN tag is ahead and the git tag is a branch.

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove tags/1.0.0
Commit changes
Create tag
```

Though I puzzled why did you mention git?